# bash: last background process differs

Tags: bash, process, background

Can anyone explain why I do not get consequently the same cmd-output for the ps-command in the bash-sequence (on RHEL 7.4) below?:

```
# while [[ ${X} != "123" ]]
> do
>   sleep 1 &
>   QWE=$!
>   ps --no-headers -o uid,pid,cmd -p ${QWE}
>   sleep 1
> done
[1] 19223
    0 19223 sleep 1
[1]+  Done                    sleep 1
[1] 19226
    0 19226 sleep 1
[1]+  Done                    sleep 1
[1] 19229
    0 19229 -bash
[1]+  Done                    sleep 1
[1] 19232
    0 19232 -bash
[1]+  Done                    sleep 1
[1] 19241
    0 19241 -bash
[1]+  Done                    sleep 1
[1] 19244
    0 19244 sleep 1
[1]+  Done                    sleep 1
[1] 19255
    0 19255 -bash
^C
```

Comment: Please edit your Q to include the expected output, Good luck.

Comment: Incidentally, this behavior is by design. If you're trying to force a certain order of output, you have a significant task ahead of you. Good luck.

Comment: I would expect the command of the "last backup process" ($!) to be the same consequently (so "sleep 1" or "-bash"), and not to differ arbitrairly.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive each time you are displaying the pid of the ps command that is getting executed.

Please let me know if I misunderstood your request here.

Comment: My concern is the "cmd"-output of the ps-command, which differs between "sleep 1" and "-bash".

Answer (score 0):

You see sometimes `-bash` and sometimes `sleep 1` because the command `sleep 1 &` causes `bash` first to *clone* itself and then to *execve* `sleep`. What you see depends on whether the `ps`  executes quickly enough to peek in before the *execve* happens.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable.